# Алгоритм/Сервис для сравнения строк на логичное совпадение?

Tags: алгоритм, строки, сервисы

Есть ли какой алгоритм/сервис для сравнения строк на логичное совпадение?
Что я имею введу под *логичное совпадение*, вот пример:

`hello world` и `world hello` по смыслу равны на 100%.

`hello world` и `hello sunny world` по смыслу равны ~ 60-70%.

Смотрел в сторону [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) ну там другой принцип работы.

Так же  [Myer's diff algorithm](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) - тут что то ближе. По факту можно находить различия и их уже сравнивать.

Есть еще что-то? Спасибо

Comment: `hello world` и `world hello` совершенно не равны на 100% по смыслу. Это в русском языке можно переставлять слова без изменения смысла, в английском так можно далеко не всегда.

Comment: См. [Алгоритмы на строках](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_алгоритмов#Алгоритмы_на_строках). Можно испоьзовать сразу несколько, чтобы добиться результата. К сожалению, на русском описаны не все.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, мне по факту не нужен 100% результат устроит 60-70% т.к делается все это все на уровне `experimental` для переводов коротких строк и сравнения перевода введенный пользователем с переводом google.translate | google.translate